# @font-face not working even in test files?

Tags: fonts, font-face

OK, I've used this many times before but this is killing me, I've separated out the text from the customer's site but still can't get font-face working? I've even tried different font files but nothing. Here is my CSS -

```
@charset "utf-8";

html { 
    padding:0; 
    margin:0;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;}


@font-face {
    font-family: lucida; /*a name given to our new font family*/
    src: url(‘garamond-webfont.ttf’),
    url(‘garamond-webfont.woff’),
    url(‘garamond-webfont.eot’); /* IE9 */ }

body { 
    margin:0; 
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
    font-family: lucida; }
```

And here is the html -

```
<html>

<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css"/>

</head>

<body>

Testing Font Face

</body>

</html>
```

And it does not work, arghh - help please.

Comment: Those don't look like normal apostrophes to me.

Answer (score 1):

I have three suggestions to check:

It is because there is already a font named 'lucida';
You appear to have smart-quotes in your css, rather than plain apostrophes;
You haven't put "Testing Font Face" in a tag (other than body).

Comment: That's a good one. @font-face only fires when the required font isn't there; people often forget that.

Comment: Thank you for responding, I am very grateful. Oddly, I have fixed it, I just copied and pasted some code from one of my other sites, I then changed the name of the font files and voila. The code looks no different but appears to be working? Most strange.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing ‘ ’ with ' ' for your uri to the font.

Comment: Odd, what's the difference between the characters?

Comment: If you look at the apostrophes in your posted css, you should notice that one is arched to the right, and one to the left. These are called smart-quotes, and are special characters that you might normally see in a Word document, but shouldn't be in a plain-text css file.

Comment: Andrew Gibson it's right, only i didn't know how to name those characters.